# Merge nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(
  0 => array(
    'name' => 'group_one',
    'options' => array('foo'=>'one', 'bar'=>'two')
  ),
  1 => array(
    'name' => 'group_two',
    'options' => array('baz'=>'three', 'qux'=>'four')
  )
);
```

I want to merge all of the nested `options` arrays into one, so it'll be like this:

```
array(
  'foo' => 'one',
  'bar' => 'two',
  'baz' => 'three',
  'qux' => 'four'
);
```

I have a feeling this is very simple, but anything I try seems too convoluted. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a multidimensional array into a single dimensional one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216993/converting-a-multidimensional-array-into-a-single-dimensional-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something slicker but this should work for any length of array:

```
$result = array();

foreach($array as $v) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $v['options']);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => one
    [bar] => two
    [baz] => three
    [qux] => four
)
```

Comment: This gives me an array of the options arrays. Not just the key/values inside them. `array(array('foo'=>'one'),array('bar'=>'two'),etc);`

Comment: No, the code I posted gives exactly what you posted in your question. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a424686bad63f470c048e8819d81d1a5f8e7b0d

Comment: You're right. My mistake. My data is incorrect in the question but you've answered this one correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = $array[0]['options'] + $array[1]['options'];
```

You can also use `array_merge()`

Answer (score 0):

or try to get a new array like this

```
   $array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'group_one',
        'options' => array('foo' => 'one', 'bar' => 'two')
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'group_two',
        'options' => array('baz' => 'three', 'qux' => 'four')
    )
);


$options = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {
    foreach ($arr['options'] as $key => $value) {
        $options[$key] = $value;
    }
}


echo '<pre>';
print_r($options);
echo '<pre>';
```